# get the word for filename for each locale

Tags: excel, excel-formula, locale

I use the following formula to extract the filename of a workbook to build a hyperlink with it:

`=MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("[",CELL("filename",A1))+1,FIND("]", CELL("filename",A1))-FIND("[",CELL("filename",A1))-1)`

However I personally use a Dutch version of excel, therefore I translated the "filename" manually to suit my locale. Now I have a international contact that wants to use this in a workbook as well, but in a number of different locale's.

Is there a way to extract "filename" using a formula, as to get the appropriate word for any given locale?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing the string "filename" is in cell `A1` then `=CELL($A$1,A1)` should work.

In my German Excel then I can change `A1` to "dateiname" and it works also.

But `=CELL("filename",A1)` should work in any locale.

Of course in my German Excel it is `=ZELLE("filename"; A1)`. But the function's name translation Excel is doing by default if the same file is opened in another locale or with another language version of Excel. The Excel file itself stores the English function names only.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the problem. Yes excel converts the formula just fine. The problem is the word "filename", because it is between " , it is considered as text, and will not be translated. Try out your '=ZELLE("filname";A1)' It will give you the #VALUE error

Comment: No, `=ZELLE("filename"; A1)` works without error in my German Excel 2016.

Comment: Ah that is curious. I get an error. Using excel for mac 2011.

Comment: Just tried `=ZELLE("filename"; A1)` works without error in my German Excel 2007 also. Both Windows. So it must be related to MAC Excel. So use `=CELL($A$1,A1)` having the string "filename" in `A1` and your international contact has to change that cell value then.